# Bootstrap modal - Don't disable the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using bootstrap modal in my code and I'd like it to just pop up without making the page behind totally unusable.

```
$("<div>")
  .attr({ id: "myModal", tabindex: "-1", role: "dialog" })
  .addClass("modal fade")
  .append(
    $("<div>")
      .addClass("modal-dialog modal-lg")
      .attr("role", "document")
      .append(
        $("<div>")
          .addClass("modal-content")
          .append(
            $("<div>")
              .addClass("modal-header")
              .addClass("bg-info text-white")
              .html("EXAMPLE"),
            $("<div>")
              .addClass("modal-body")
              .html("EXAMPLE"),
            $("<div>")
              .addClass("modal-footer")
              .html("EXAMPLE")
          )
      )
  )
  .modal({
    backdrop: false
  });
```

This makes a Modal without backdrop, but the modal-dialog div don't allow me to use my page behind. I want to be allowed to scroll the page, to click on buttons and keep my modal visible.

Comment: you can do this by adding this css `.modal {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
body.modal-open {
    overflow: scroll;
}`

Comment: Just fyi a modal is called modal because it changes the modus of the page, it's intent is to block the page until the user dealt with the important dialog in the modal. If you don't been a modal, you can look up lightboxes and popups. But Bootstrap modal can be easily hacked.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I still use modals to do what I want, look at the answer of @Mahatmasamatman if you want to see how we solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the modal, it adds 'modal-open' class to *body* tag, preventing the user from scrolling/using the page.

**Note**: that is the **intended functionality** of modals. Maybe what you are looking for could be achieved with popovers, or a custom element.

If you want to to proceed with the current implementation, you can remove modal-open class from body

```
$("body").removeClass("modal-open");
```

or add custom css

```
body.modal-open { overflow: scroll; }
```

Comment: This is the perfect solution for making the body scrollable ! Thanks a lot.
But this still prevent the click behind the .modal and .modal-dialog divs. Maybe I could make those divs fit to the .modal-content ?

Comment: Unusable as in you cannot click or navigate through the page? The whole modal gets placed across your whole screen, even though the 'dialog' appears to be smaller, so you actually might still be clicking on the modal. Try adding some width and height to .modal class in order to shrink it. Other than that I'd have to see a jsfiddle.

Comment: It worked !
      $('.modal').css('width', 'auto');
Thanks a lot, you solved all my problems

Comment: + Don't forget to set the height to auto too if you want to be able to click above and under your modal